# Finding chi-square value between a model contour plot and x,y data

Tags: statistics, curve-fitting, contour, data-fitting, chi-squared

I have x and y coordinates of experimental data, of which I am trying to fit an ellipse to.
My x data is in a list `xpix`, and my y data is in a list `ypix`. I have fitted the equation of a rotated using ellipse `np.meshgrid` and `np.contour`.

```
xpix = [.....]
ypix = [.....]
x = np.linspace(-80, 80, 100)
y = np.linspace(-80, 80, 100)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)
#equation of rotated ellipse below, uses X and Y
F = (X*np.cos(63*np.pi/180) -Y*np.sin(63*np.pi/180))**2 /352.8676 + (X*np.sin(63*np.pi/180) + 
Y*np.cos(63*np.pi/180))**2 / 6300 - 1
plt.contour(X,Y,F,[0])
```

And just for context, the following shows my plot: [image: model ellipse (purple solid line) and experimental data (blue dots)]

Of which I'm fairly happy with, hence I would like to find the chi-square value between my contour data and my `xpix, ypix` data. I'm quite lost on how to do this, as the contour data has a totally different array structure - it has plotted the array values which best fit an ellipse with the fourth argument in `plt.contour` = `[0]`. I think, in order to do this manually, I would have to sieve through all `X,Y` values to find the ones used to build this ellipse. Is there a faster way to do this directly? I know that to use `stats.chisquare(ypix,y_model)`, for example, `ypix` and `y_model` would need to have the same shape.

Once I understand how to do this, I aim to run a function which varies the rotation angle, semi minor and major axes iteratively until the chi square is maximised.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer to the question. For information only, this is a comparison of the methods of fitting.

Instead of the non-linear regression implemented in the software used by the OP, the direct linear regression gives the results below :

[image]

Note : Since the data was not available on numerical form in the question, the data was generated thanks to scanning the picture edited in the question. So the data used above is certainely not correct. All the more as the points on the picture are not points but circular marks.

Comment: Thank you, to be honest the data you've put up is extremely close to what I used. May I ask how you went about doing this? Also, is there a way of obtaining the semi-major and semi-minor axes, which I need for to work out the ellipticity?

Comment: The above data was generated with a software in scanning the image posted in your question. The coordinates of each pixel on the same color (blue in this case) are computed. Each cluster of pixels is replaced by only one point at center of the cluster. This is not always reliable for overlapping clusters.
// 
The length of semi-axes can be computed with the formulas (21) and (22) from : https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Ellipse.html . The symbols are different from above : a=A ; b=B/2 ; c=C ; d=D/2 ; f=E/2 ; g= -1 .

Comment: Another method to compute the semi-axes length consists in writting the equation of the axe (linear) knowing the coordinates of the center and the tilt angle. The intersection of this straight line with the ellipse (since the equation of the ellipse is known) gives the coordinates of the top, then the lenght between the center and the top.

Comment: The formulas for the semi-axis lenght are added at the end of the answer. Also a typo is corrected in the formula for the tilt angle.

Comment: These have all been extremely helpful and interesting. In this regression model, what stopping criteria is in place to decide when a fit is 'good enough'? Do you check this with a chi squared value?

Comment: In fact there is no stopping criteria because there is nothing to stop. The calculus is linear : it is not recursive, there is no algorithm iteratif into it. If a specific criteria of fitting (LMSE,or LMSRE, or LMAE, or etc.) this method of the linear regression kind is not convenient. This is commented in the paper (in French) : https://fr.scribd.com/doc/14819165/Regressions-coniques-quadriques-circulaire-spherique .